# Actualizar un div con ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

hice una galeria de imagenes con paginacion, mi problema está en que tal paginacion la hago utilizando un form y enviando los datos directamente al controlador utilizando `C#`. Ésto lo que me provoca es que se actualice TODA la pagina web, cuando solamente necesito que se actualice la sección de las imagenes:

Estoy intentando de hacerlo con Jquery pero me está redireccionando a la funcion que utilizo para traerme los datos (`PaginacionGaleriaImagenes2()`)

`PaginacionGaleriaImagenes2()` me trae los datos correctos, ya que tengo un `console.log(result)` y me trae la lista correctamente, solamente necesito ayuda en actualizar el div..

Para eso estuve utilizando ésta funcion pero no está funcionando correctamente, me redirecciona a `PaginacionGaleriaImagenes2`, la cual es una funcion Json, no una vista

```
$("#ajax_submit_siguiente").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("prevent Default")

    var data = {
        'paginacion': 'siguiente',
        'entrega': $("#btnSiguientePaginacion").val()
    }
    console.log(data)

    console.log("Entra AJAX")
    $.ajax({

        url: '/Home/PaginacionGaleriaImagenes2/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);

            /*$("#container-galeria-imagenes").load(window.location.href + " #container-galeria-imagenes");*/
            $('#galeria2').load(window.location.href);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
})
```

Y esta es mi seccion de la galeria:

```
<section id="galeria-imagenes">
     <div class="galeria">
         <div class="container-galeria-imagenes" id="container-galeria-imagenes">
            @foreach (var pd in Model)
            {
                if (img != pd.getImagenes().ToString() && pd.getCodigoImagen() == numEntregaActual)
                {
                      <div class="gallery-item columnaPedido item-galeria-imagenes" id="galeria2" data-index="@cont">
                      <img alt="Image" class="imgPedido" id="@cont" src="@pd.getImagenes()" data-img-mostrar="@cont" name="imgIndividual" />
                       <label class="d-flex justify-content-center" for="@pd.getCodigoImagen()">@pd.getFecha() @pd.getHora()</label>
                      </div>
                }
           }
        </div>
   </div>
  <div class="paginacion-galeria">
   <form action="~/Home/PaginacionGaleriaImagenes2" method="post" id="ajax_submit_volver">
         <button id="btnVolverPaginacion" value="@item.getNumeroEntrega()" type="submit">
                                        Volver
          </button>
   </form>                                                                
   <div class="pagina-actual">Pagina <span class="numero-pagina-actual"></span></div>
       <form action="~/Home/PaginacionGaleriaImagenes2" method="post" id="ajax_submit_siguiente">
          <button id="btnSiguientePaginacion" value="@item.getNumeroEntrega()" type="submit">
                                        Siguiente
           </button>
       </form>                                  
   </div>
</section>
```

EDIT:

Al parecer no me están trayendo los datos en formato json...

```
0:{imgFrenteDni_tr_fecha: '', imgDorsoDni_tr_fecha: '', path: ''}
1:{imgFrenteDni_tr_fecha: '', imgDorsoDni_tr_fecha: '', path: ''}
2:{imgFrenteDni_tr_fecha: '', imgDorsoDni_tr_fecha: '', path: ''}
3:{imgFrenteDni_tr_fecha: '', imgDorsoDni_tr_fecha: '', path: ''}
4:{imgFrenteDni_tr_fecha: '', imgDorsoDni_tr_fecha: '', path: ''}
5:{imgFrenteDni_tr_fecha: '', imgDorsoDni_tr_fecha: '', path: ''}
6:{imgFrenteDni_tr_fecha: '', imgDorsoDni_tr_fecha: '', path: ''}
7:{imgFrenteDni_tr_fecha: '', imgDorsoDni_tr_fecha: '', path: ''}
8:{imgFrenteDni_tr_fecha: '', imgDorsoDni_tr_fecha: '', path: ''}
```

Comment: ¿Estás tratando de cargar la URL en curso dentro de un `<div>`? Además, veo que has intentado usar una URL con `#`. Recuerda que todo lo que hay tras un `#` en una URL es interpretado en el navegador por el cliente y nunca llega al servidor. ¿Podrías decir qué contiene `result` cuando devuelve la llamada al servidor y qué debes agregar al div?

Comment: Habia visto en algunas respuestas que utilizaban `#` pero para los id de las secciones

Comment: Si, disculpame, ahora edito la pregunta mostrando lo que muestra

Comment: Ahi lo pude subir @OscarGarcia, tuve varios problemas

Comment: Si, es lo que me está devolviendo el response/result

Comment: [Creo que es mejor que continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143107/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-bilbit-bolson). Borro los mensajes bajo la pregunta para que queden trasladados al chat.